# Camel try catch in onException

Tags: error-handling, apache-camel

I'm having issues with onException in my Camel context. I'm using a general error handler, that tries to extract additional error information from the exchange using xpath when exceptions occurs. The onException contains a try/catch clause, preventing additional errors from being raised.

```
<onException>
  <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
  <handled>
    <constant>true</constant>
  </handled>
  <!-- Try to get additional error information from the exchange-->
  <doTry>
    <setProperty name="error.code">
      <xpath resultType="java.lang.String">//*[local-name()='error'][1]/@code</xpath>
    </setProperty>
    <doCatch>
      <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
    </doCatch>
  </doTry>
</onException>
```

The problem is that the try/catch doesn't seem to catch exception when xpath fails, for example when body is not xml. Instead the FatalFallbackErrorHandler is invoked and the following exception is logged:

```
Content is not allowed in prolog.: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The try/catch does actually catch the exception when xpath fails, and the FatalFallbackErrorHandler is **not** invoked. The doTry/doCatch works as expected even though it's within the onException.

An error with traceback is logged by Camels jaxp XmlConverter, but no exception is raised from onException.

https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/639eba1f66d0e001a033d417baa07b814c3d6994/core/camel-xml-jaxp/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/converter/jaxp/XmlConverter.java#L1105

Answer (score 1):

As you observed, the try/catch in the `onException` block helps nothing.

Whenever **an Exception occurs during error handling**, the `FatalFallbackErrorHandler` kicks in. This is the "emergency break" of Camel. You can't change this and it does the following:

- catches the Exception
- logs a Warning
- sets the Exception on the Exchange
- **stops any further routing**

This is to prevent endless circular loops between error handlers or other problems that can arise when error handlers throw errors.

---

What you could try (I think I never tried this) is to create a dedicated `direct` route for the collection of error information.

You call it from the error handler with `.to("direct:collectErrorInformation")`.

If the xpath throws an error, you are in a normal route and if you also add an `onException` block for the validation error, you can handle this normally.

Give it a try if you like to.

Comment: I find this behavior a bit strange, especially since <doTry> is defined within <onException> in the camel-spring xml schema. I would expect any exception that is raised within a try/catch to be handled within that clause, regardless if it's within error handling or else where.